# What benefits does using a struct pointer give over just a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am a bit confused about this because I was looking at some code for a dispatcher, and they defined a struct PCB (process control block) that basically contains a bunch of information about a running process and a struct queue. The queue basically just manages the order that the processes are executed, but also ocassionaly moves the processes across queues (eg. move a PCB from queue1 to queue2). The queue struct is essentially defined as

```
struct Queue{
   pcbptr front;
   pcbptr back;
}
```

where pcbptr is defined as

```
typedef pcb * pcbptr
```

I am a bit confused about why you would use a pcbptr in this case and not simply define queue to use pcb?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Because it's a linked data structure. While it's possible to create a linked data structure without dynamically allocating the members, it's rarely useful to do so, and usually (including here) defeats the purpose of having a linked structure in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the response. By the way, does this mean I can still assign int values to a pcbptr? Say the pcb struct contains a parameter called int value, can I just go like pcbptr->value = 1?

Comment: It needs to be accessed by name, not datatype. front->value = 1; is valid

Comment: Plus you obviously need to allocate memory for the struct (with `malloc()` or friends) before trying to assign values to its members.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simply because of time. It is way faster to have a pointer to a different struct than to have a copy of the struct by value. 
Also, the people using the Queue may wish to modify the PCBs, which they would not be able to do if the PCBs were passed by value.

Also, if you were asking about why they didn't simply use PCB * and not typedef a PCB * to be pcbptr, that is all just down to naming convention. They are exactly the same functionally.

Answer (score 0):

Just think about a queue and what it means at different lengths.

If it is 0, you need to tell that somehow (we do this normally by just setting the pointers for front and back to NULL).

If it is 1, both the front and the back need to point to the same thing.

If it is 2, they point at different things, but have a link going from one to the other.

If it is 3, front points at first one, the first one points at the middle one, and the middle one points at the last done, and back points at the last one.

So no matter what you do, with a variable size like this you need to use pointers. for middle ones.. why bother making the front and back anything but a pointer? (especially since it's faster to change a pointer than to try to move a struct around and the code is about 100x more complicated)